# ARM Loop stops executing instructions

Tags: loops, assembly, arm

I'm working on a program that counts the number of 1's and 0's of a binary string.
My CountOnes subroutine works as expected:

```
countOnes   MOV r1, r0      ;mov random number into r1
            TEQ r1, #0      ;test if all 0
            MOVEQ   pc, r14     ;if all 0's, brake
onesloop    SUB r2, r1, #1  ;subtract 1
            AND r1, r2, r1  ;and on r1 and r2
            ADD r9, r9, #1  ;increment loop counter
            TEQ r1, #0      ;test if all 0
            BNE onesloop    ;if not all 0's, loop
            MOV     pc, r14     ;return


countZeros  MOV r1, r0      ;mov random number in r1
            MVN r8, #0      ;fill r8 with 1's
            TEQ r1, r8      ;test if number is all 1's
            MOVEQ   pc, r14     ;if all 1's, break
zerosloop   ADD r2, r1, #1  ;add 1 to r2
            AND r1, r2, r1  ;and r1 and r2
            ADD r9, r9, #1  ;increment loop count
            TEQ r1, r8      ;test if all ones
            BNE zerosloop   ;if not all 1's, loop
            MOV pc, r14     ;return
```

However, my countZeros subroutine loops indefinitely, and after looking at it with a debugger, it turns out that the **ADD** and **AND** instructions are only executed the first time through the loop(which is the reason for the infinite loop), however, the entire loop is not broken, register 9 continues to be incremented every iteration.
I can't think of any reason for those instructions to stop being executed.  Anyone encounter this behavior before or know what would cause it?  If you need more info on anything just ask.

Comment: If this is not just an exercise in assembly, take a look at [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) and [Hacker's
Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `zerosloop` you need to `OR r1, r2, r1` instead of `AND`.

Also you should use `CMN r1, #1` to find out whether `r1` is all `1`s.

Comment: Ok, changed the and to or and it instantly started responding.
I'll take a look at using CMN like you said.  Thanks a lot for looking at it.